# Calling variables in a send_email call in Python

Tags: python, django, class, email, variables

I'm trying to make it so that the body of the text of the email includes a lot of variables I declared earlier in a class:

```
title_text = ' Has Been Ordered'
title = instance.product
email=EmailMessage(title+title_text,  'hello', to=['youremail@gmail.com'])
email.send()

class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    product = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    vendor = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

To clarify, where it says 'hello', I want to be able to insert both text such as "hello, this is the product you ordered" and then the variable of the class PurchaseOrder product.

Comment: Please don't overuse emphasis formatting; it only makes your post look like you are shouting.

Comment: Emails are just *text*; use normal string formatting techniques to generate text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use string formatting.

```
>>> var = 'insert text here'
>>> "hello {}".format(var)
'hello insert text here'
```

Comment: why not just "hello %s" % 'insert text here'